# Migrating eclipse project to android studio shows install error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have migrated my eclipse project to Android Studio, but while running, it is giving me a dialog with the below message:

> Installation failed with message Invalid File:
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk.

It is possible that this issue can be resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the APK,* if it is present*, and then re-installing?

When I click the `ok` button it shows the following session error in my run tab.

> 05/11 11:54:35: Launching storeTrack-storeTrack $ adb install-multiple
>   -r D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
>   D:\andro\stockApp\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
>   D:\Anil\android_projects\storeTrack\storeTrack\build\outputs\apk\storeTrack-debug.apk  $ adb shell pm uninstall com.c2info.storetrack
>   DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APKs

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall it from the device.
2. Perform clean install on the device.